# "Unable to Connect to any of specified MySQL hosts in WPF c#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I am trying to connect to MySQL Database from my WPF application, I have set up connection and also checked test connection, and give me message that

```
"Test Connection Succeeded";
```

but when I debug the program, it gives me error message like this:

```
"Unable to Connect to any of specified MySQL hosts";
```

See my code:

```
server = "localhost";
        database = "xx";
        uid = "xx";
        password = "xxx";
        string connectionString;

        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Its headache for me how to deal with this one?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks!!

Comment: Do you really expect us to answer that without seeing *any* of your code?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar sorry for it, see my edit brother, I have posted code of connectionstring.

Comment: Two thoughts: a) can you connect to the server using any other tool on your PC? b) Please try `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` to build the connection string instead of manually concatenating it.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar yes, I succeeded using "TOAD for MySQL"!! so what should I need to do?

Comment: As I said, try to use the `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` to ensure you get a valid connection string. Also check the port number.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I am really sorry, I do not know about "MySQLConnectionStringBuilder", can you post the code?Thank for ur time.

Comment: Read the documentation for `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` and use `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` the same way. Alternatively, read the documentation for `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I tried using "MySqlConnectionStringBuilder" but nothing changes.Thank you.